# Can you regain your post questions privilege by changing tags?

Tags: support, questions, privileges, posting

On my Stack Overflow account, I had some past questions (that I deleted) that had tags like JavaScript and [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), but didn't provide any code, as they were only somewhat related. But, the community bot had put comments on those posts asking for code.

I responded by deleting the question, but never changing the tags. I think that in some way this influenced how I lost the privilege to delete questions.

One example of this is a question that I had about [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel), about the Node.js application (which is deleted now). I decided to use the tags cPanel and Node.js in the question. Is there a way that I could fix the tags, even with a deleted question, and will this help me to regain my post questions privilege?

Comment: "I think that in some way this influenced how I lost the privilege to delete questions." - delete questions? Post new questions I think you mean

Comment: You were question banned because you deleted your questions instead of editing them and addressing the problem with them

Answer (score 3):

Removing your question is not a privilege (but asking new question is). There are rules to limit question removing. For example, if you have an accepted & upvoted answer, you will not be able to remove it.

In your case, the "*Community Bot"* comment asks for code because someone on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) chose *Share feedback*. For them, your question didn't fully respect Stack Overflow guidelines.

As it's posted by a bot, you can reply what you want, but people will not get a notification. You can edit your post (including tags), and the question will be "bumped" and can go back in review according to what you do.